# Deleting old snapshots SQL

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, snapshot-replication

This may be a silly or dumb question but...

We just changed the snapshot path and I was wondering if the cleanup job also clears up the old snapshots from the previous folder path or is it something that has to be done manually either with transact or just click delete?

Thanks!!

Comment: Database snapshots ? There is no MS supplied job for these so whether the cleanup works would depend on how the job is coded. To delete it you can right click on the relevant icon under Database Snapshots in SSMS and pick "Delete"

Answer (score 1):

Distribution cleanup agent purges the non-latest folders

[image]

But, the snapshot agent will only try once to remove the previous snapshot files so if those files were locked at that moment (by the merge agent e.g.), it is possible that snapshot files will be left over.